# Why AND gate is positive Logic?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Why AND gate is considered as Positive Logic and OR gate as Negative Logic

Comment: what happens to output if both inputs to OR are low?  What is this theorem called?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 both low then output =  low in OR gate. ie False or 0 value. But how is this considered as negative logic

Comment: I would suggest looking up 'assertion level logic' where low and high lose meaning.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah got it..Thank you very much

Comment: We can also prove this by Property of Duality i think..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is de Morgan's Rule for AND Gate?

### Answer:

AND = the negative logic rule using the OR gate.

Whereas the AND could replace an OR gate using the negative logic, where 1=true, 0=false for positive logic.

These two reciprocal equivalent rules are called de Morgan's Rule

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fppiGp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>